# Incorrect output for an array, java

Tags: java, arrays

The code below simulates dice, I am interested in the number of times the two dice will match and the idea is to print out 0 and 1 at first to show how often this happens. Then to print the array which should contain when was obtained the "double", ex: the first would contain 3, which is the number of throw before the first double...a limit of lets say 45 given by the user will end the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int limiteDoublons = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre lancer: ").trim());
    int[] t = new int[limiteDoublons];
    int d1 = 0;
    int d2 = 0;
    int nbDoublons = 0;
    int nbLancer = 0;
    do {
        for(int x = 0; x<limiteDoublons;x++){
            //shuffle
            d1 = (int)(Math.random() * 7) + 1;
            d2 = (int)(Math.random() * 7) + 1;
            //si doublon print 1 et augmente le nbDoublon
            //donne la valeur du tableau suivante ;a valeur de nblancer
            if(d1 == d2) {
            System.out.print("1");
            nbDoublons++;
             t[x] = nbLancer;
            }
            else {
            System.out.print("0");
            }
            if ((nbLancer + 1) % 20 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            nbLancer++;
        }           
    } while (nbDoublons < limiteDoublons);

    System.out.println("\nOrdre des boulons: ");
    Arrays.sort(t);
    for (int i = 0; i < limiteDoublons; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%1$4d", t[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
10001101100000000000
01001100000000000000
00000000000000000000
00101100010100110010
00000000000000100000
00001100010010000000
00000000100000000000
00001000000000000000
01000100000011000101
00000010001000000100
00000001000000000100
01010000000000100001
01100100100000001000
10000000001010010000
00001000000000000000
000000000100000
Ordre des boulons: 
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   7   8  21  25  69  74  78  94 105
 109 112 161 165 173 177 179 186 190 207
 217 221 223 234 241 242 245 248 256 260
 270 272 275 284 309
```

What is unexpected is the 0 following "Ordre des boulons". It doesnt make sense that I would get my first double at the throw 0 and so on...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array issue, can't solve it Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412988/array-issue-cant-solve-it-java)

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm asking it again but its more elaborated, and I'm trying to get an answer, can anyone give me one?

Comment: Why all the zeroes? Because you didn't assign anything to the array t when the random results don't match.

Comment: edited, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @KCWong my array t is only for throws with doubles...should I make a second array? I don't get it

Comment: Using a debugger or even the good old println() will allow you to solve this one on your own...

Comment: You allocated the array t to be the size of the amount of dice rolls you do. Even if you don't save a value to t, there is still an item for each roll. If you only want to keep the doubles, then you should use a List instead, which is an array with dynamic size.

Comment: @shmosel this would mean that I would have thrown, in my present output, doubles at throw 0, 11 times in this case...

Comment: @KCWong thanks for answer, I didn't know I could use array list, I'm new to programming and I am still learning the array functionning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting all the zeros because you're updating the array at index `x`, which is counting *throws*, not *doubles*. You should use `nbDoublons` instead:

```
t[nbDoublons] = nbLancer;
nbDoublons++;
```

Comment: Actually, `nbLancer` is counting throws. `x` is just the array index for the given round.

Comment: I got a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 45
 at Lab08D.main(Lab08D.java:22)

Comment: @dtrembl5 Drop the `x` loop and that will go away.

Comment: @Andreas It's counting throws in the current round. But the point is the same.

Comment: @dtrembl5 That's because you're rolling extra times and getting extra doubles. You'll have to figure out what you want to do when you hit the intended count.

Comment: @Andreas and shmosel thank you for the answer, the for loop was the problem. I removed it and replaced t[nbDoublons], it now works. Now I understand! Thanks!